# Is capture image Saved in Photo Library of iPhone using phonegap

Tags: jquery, iphone, cordova

I capture image from device using phonegap, now I want to save that image in photogalary of iPhone. Please let me know that Is it possible or not??

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccessCapturePhoto, onFailCapturePhoto, {
                    quality : 50,
                    destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                                            saveToPhotoAlbum : true
            });
```

I use  `saveToPhotoAlbum : true`, due to this images saved in photogallery.

Answer (score 0):

just add this line when you want to save image in gallary

```
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, id completionTarget, SEL completionSelector, void *contextInfo);
```

You only need completionTarget, completionSelector and contextInfo if you want to be notified when the image is done saving, otherwise you can pass in nil.

for example..

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(yourImage,nil,nil,nil);
```